# Covert string with timezone to Date

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Here is the date string

```
NSString * dateString = @"Mon Sep 29 14:40:00 2014 PET";
```

How to convert it into NSDate?

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy zzz"];
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Above code doesn't work.
what is the correct date format for above case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is your timezone definition (`PET`), because that is not on list of the recognisable timezones (please don't ask why not); this timezone is mostly known as `UTC-5` in Apple's system, therefore:

---

```
NSString *_dateString = @"Mon Sep 29 14:40:00 2014 PET";
_dateString = [_dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PET" withString:@"UTC-5"];
NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[_dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[_dateFormatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy zzz"];
NSDate *_date = [_dateFormatter dateFromString:_dateString];
NSLog(@"date : %@", _date);
```

---

and the console says:

```
date : 2014-09-29 19:40:00 +0000
```

which is the correct representation of the original date in `GMT+0` timezone.

Comment: This solution would work only if time zone string comes as PET :) But i got the root cause for the issue. Thanks holex

Comment: @BodaSira, yes, that is true, this solution is for the timezone `PET` only. it would be easier if every back-end service provides the timezones in `GMT±xxxx` format, that can be recognisable without ambiguity. :)